# Generating reports in asp.net mvc 4 using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create report in Asp.net mvc 4 using stores procedure.
At same time I need to pass EmpID and date as inputs to procedure.

Please can any one provide sample solution or any good link that will satisfy me.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple solution will be to try the below:-

1. Create a Http Post JSONResult Method in your Controller which takes EmpId & Date as Parameters
2. Create an Ajax Method in your view which calls and posts the EmpID & Date to above JSONResult Method
3. Execute your stored Procedure in the JsonResult Method in your controller, convert the stored procedure resultset to JsonResult and return it back to Ajax Call.
4. By Using the returned Json Response data, you can prepare and display any type of report like table, pie charts, etc

Comment: thanks. but how to convert the stored procedure resultset to JsonResult and return it back to Ajax Call. @Sreekaanth T